# CrossRider extension is not working on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser-extension, crossrider

We are using CrossRider to develop an extension for Internet Explorer. I added alerts in the background and in extension.js, but there are no alerts when I install this extension. What is the problem?

**background.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    alert("appAPI.platform = " + appAPI.platform);
});
```

**extension.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    alert("appAPI.platform = " + appAPI.platform);
});
```

Our Extension ID is 43889. I'm using Internet Explorer 11 but this extension should work on all versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: "Nothing is working" is not answerable (beside being a bad title). Please read the FAQ and try to rephrase your whole question and add more useful information for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found out there was a yellow bar at the bottom of the screen of Internet Explorer and there I had to click "enable", until I enabled the extension it was disabled and therefore no alerts happened.